# Get previous weekday + MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dayofweek

I need to get the previous weekday. So when it's monday I need to get the result friday but I can't seem to understand the WEEKDAY() function. Could someone help to start with this?

Comment: Do you really need this functionality at the database layer?

Comment: No, not really thought it would be the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WEEKDAY()` returns 0 to 6 depending on which day of the week it is.  You could put logic in the code to ignore weekend conditions, and go back to the Friday.

Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

So if `WEEKDAY(date) - 1  == 5 || WEEKDAY(date) - 1 == 6` then make it equal 4 (Friday) instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
select date_add(curdate(), interval
case weekday(curdate())
   when 0 then 5
   when 6 then -2
   else -1
end 
day);
```